# How to implement Mean Shift (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, machine-learning

I have a dataset, consisting of 61 rows and 28 columns (Category of Used Application). I am very much new with coding,I will try Machine learning algorithm for the first time, so I appreciate any help! .

This is what I have in terms of my data:

```
   Category  Calendar  Clock  Communication  Education  Entertainment  Finance   
UserId                                                                         
  1                1      1              1          9              1         0   
  2                0      1              1          0              0         0   
  3                0      1              1          0              0         0   
  4                1      1              6          0              0         0   
  5                0      1              1          1              1         0   
  6                0      0              0          0              0         0   
  7                0      1              1          0              0         0   
  8                0      1              1          0              0         0   
  9                0      0              1          0              7         0   
  10               0      1              1          0              0         0   
  11               0      2              1          0              5         0   
  13               0      0              1          0              0         0   
  14               0      1              1          0              1         0   
  15               1      1              1          0              0         0   
  16               0      1              1          0              0         0   
  17               0      0              1          1              1         0   
  19               0      1              1          0              0         0   
  20               0      0              1          0              0         0   
  21               0      1              1          0              1         0   
  .....  
  61               0      1              1          0              5         0
```

I am looking for an implementation of Mean Shift to cluster users in 3 groups with their behavior of used category .
How should i do!
Or can you give me recomendation what algorithm better to this kind of case? Such mean shift or any other.

Comment: please check: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html

Comment: demo code https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_mean_shift.html. But because you are new to programming, I believe it might be better for you to start with K-means. Mean shift is mainly used in image processing and computer vision. With mean shift you can track object based on their density